# Integer to CLI/C++ String c++

Tags: c++-cli

I am trying to make a Windows Form Application(using Microsoft Visual C++ 2010) which will take input from the user(words and definitions), and enter them into a vector of maps. Then, I am trying to show the user the number of words(the number of elements inside the vector or `vector.size()`) entered inside a label. I know that (given that numberLabel and myVector are already declared), doesn't work:

```
numberLabel->Text = myVector.size()
```

How am I supposed to approach this issue and get an integer inside a label? Thank You!

Comment: You have to convert the integer to string, may be with printf.

Comment: You should have searched the thousands, maybe millions of examples of how to convert an `int` to a string in C++.

Comment: Don't sweat the small stuff: numberLabel->Text = myVector.size().ToString();

Answer (score -1):

How about:

number_label->Text = std::to_string(myVector.size());

Comment: `Text` is a `System::String^`, not a `std::string`, and there's no *implicit* conversion between those. In this case the simple answer is `myVector.size().ToString()`